# Are keywords with the same name guaranteed to be identical?

Tags: clojure

Are Clojure keywords with the same name guaranteed to be identical? i.e. Is `(identical? :a :a)` guaranteed to return `true`?

What are the precise rules when the keywords of the same name are in different namespaces? For example, `(identical? :a ::a)` is `false`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keywords which are `=` are guaranteed to also be `identical?`, and those which are not `=` are of course guaranteed to not be `identical?`.

`:a` is different from `::a` because the latter has a namespace component and the former doesn't. How could they be identical? Identical means, the very same object reference. Since they have different characteristics they cannot be the same object.

Comment: Aren't keywords with the same name identical if they are in the same namespace?

Comment: Yes. But `:a` and `::a` are not in the same namespace. `:a` has no namespace, and `::a` is expanded at read time to be in the current namespace.